# which RDBMS or other tool provides good SQL syntax error messages?

Tags: sql, mysql, validation, compiler-errors

I use MySQL and it gives no meaningful error messages beyond "syntax wrong close to something or other". This is in sharp contrast to the sort of nice, clear error messages we are used to getting from java compiler and similar. So, are there RDBMS or sql validation tools that provide clearer, meaningful error messages?

Answer (score 1):

I've found Postgres errors to be fairly helpful.  Sometimes you have to google them to discover what they really mean, but there's many more than just 'syntax wrong', and they are all fairly specific.

Comment: Much better than MySQL, especially if using the Python 3 driver from here: http://python.projects.postgresql.org/